# excel add-in submission feedback

Tags: excel, office-js, publish, add-in, excel-addins

We have been going through the cycle of submission, refinement, submission.  Normally we get a very detailed report with the findings.  However, our most recent response from the team was a generic:

> We’re sorry, but we encountered an error while processing your app and
>   need your help to continue. Please submit your app for approval again,
>   and we will continue the validation process.

How can we get feedback on what this means, what was the root cause, and what we can do to ensure this doesn't happen. Our team wasn't notified of this issue, and only noticed it by checking the status several times a day.

When issues like this arise, is there a way to triage the issue faster or at least set it up so that we receive notifications proactively rather than passively?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is in the process of modernizing a lot of the infrastructure that processes add-in submissions (to fix the issues such as the one that affected your add-in submission) - when we complete this work in forthcoming months, you should not encounter these issues any more.  It was not caused by something you did wrong during submission time.

Until our updated services are released, I'd encourage you to check the email you used when registering with AppSource/the Office Store. Checking the Seller Dashboard site will also show you the status information.

If you have further questions, please provide the name of your add-in submission and we can contact you directly.

Thanks,
David Mowatt
Office Store Program Management

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user11119261.  If possible, we do have some other questions that might be better offline.  The name of the submission is Cost Of Capital Navigator.  The contact of record is Mick, and you can contact him.